# Protractor - getting computed style from web element using browser.executeScript works with string but fails with function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, protractor

I'm trying to verify visibility for a tooltip popup by calling `window.getComputedStyle().visibility` property using protractor framework.

When I pass a string to `executeScript` it's working fine. It's returning `visible`:

```
// elementToCheck is an ElementFinder
async getComputedStyleVisibility(elementToCheck) {
    return await browser
         .executeScript(`return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('${elementToCheck.locator().value}')).visibility`);
}
```

However, this is failing when I replace the string within `executeScript` by a function. It's returning `hidden` and **it looks like execution gets stuck** until tooltip popup disappears.

So I guess there's some synchronisation issue, but I cannot figure out what's happening:

```
// elementToCheck is an ElementFinder
async getComputedStyleVisibility(elementToCheck) {
    return await browser.executeScript(
        webElem => (window.getComputedStyle(webElem).visibility),
        await elementToCheck.getWebElement()
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass an element object (gotten from `getWebElement`) into a script to execute. Just use the working code with the code string.

Comment: Yes you can. It's mentioned in the docs: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

Comment: Hey @Bergi, if I'm right, that element is being passed to the arrow function which is executing `window.getComputedStyle()` function, not to the `executeScript` one

Comment: @SilvanBregy Ah, thanks, I didn't know it can serialise `WebElement`s.

Answer (score 0):

For making your script work as you wanted, you need to correctly access your webElement.

The [docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) say,

> Any arguments provided in addition to the script will be included as script arguments and may be referenced using the arguments object

So you need to use `arguments` object in your script. Like so:

```js
async getComputedStyleVisibility(elementToCheck) {
    return await browser.executeScript(
        () => (window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).visibility),
        await elementToCheck.getWebElement()
    );
}
```

### BUT

If you aren't restricted in some way to only use `browser.executeScript()` then you should overthink your approach.

`protractor` provides an `API` for checking if a certain element is present or similar.

#### Check an element to be present and visible for user:

```
element(by.css("#a")).isDisplayed()
    .then(isDisplayed => console.log("element displayed?", isDisplayed))
    .catch(err => console.error("Some error happedn. Element not present..", err))
```

You should use `browser.executeScript()` only as last resort in my opinion. Most of the general stuff like clicking, checking if present, etc. is already there, in a handy way, provided by `protractor`.

Comment: Thanks Silvan. I just tried your code but I got same result.

I strongly agree with you. We're commonly using `isDisplayed()` or `isPresent()` as well as expected conditions, but in this case we have this specific element which is only working with `browser.executeScript()`

Comment: Hmm, It seems like when getting `hidden` as result, the function call happened correclty in both formats. Have you double checked the element passed is the correct  one, and isn't there possibility for the element, not to be displayed? Say, When adding `browser.sleep()` before calling `getComputedStyleVisibility()`, the problem still occurs? (just thoughts..)

Comment: Hey @Silvan, the point is that I'm only getting `hidden` when I'm passing a function to `executeScript`, while I'm getting `visible` if passing a string.

I just tried adding `browser.sleep()` before calling `getComputedStyleVisibility()` as well as before hovering to trigger tooltip popup. No differences.

I can always see the element there and when I inspect with dev tools I can see I'm using proper selector for that element.